# java.lang.NullPointerException at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:30)

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2013, xamarin-studio

I'm using xamarin in visual studio 2013. But I am getting the following error when I open `main.axml` with design view,

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:30)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:187)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:239)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:702)
>       at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
>       at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: My only suggestion is try opening the same project with VS2017. You can get the community version.

Comment: It's definitely not a duplicate of that link, this is a specific error in code that the user has no control over (I'm having the same problem myself right now)

Answer (score 0):

it is probably related to a bug coming out from one of the latest xamarin update, as [discussed here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92892/designer-suddenly-stops-working-for-one-project)

**Update**
Since I found the Xamarin visual editor virtually unusable due to the amount of bugs and quirks, I decided to install Android Studio and I'm actually using its cool visual editor, then I simply copy and paste the XML code produced into my axml file.